# How to block a specific site's directory in windows?

Tags: windows, hosts-file

How can I block a specific directory of a website as e.g. http://example.com/**someSite**
unfortunately the hosts file is not an option since you can only block whole domains there and any "/" just destroys these rules.

This is just for my personal protection against visiting some sites too often, while i still have to be able to get to the other sites of that domain (as e.g. example.com/someOtherSite)

Would be great if someone knows a solution regarding this topic.

Comment: That's not a subdomain. Subdomain in `subdomain.domain.tld` is a subdomain.

Comment: wasn't sure and edited it. but does sub-site describe it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome you could use StayFocusd extension to help you stay away, you an specify them in there, but unfortunately that's not system wide.

Answer (score 0):

The [**BlockSites addon for Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3145/) seems to be able to do this.  You can use wildcards to block certain paths of websites, by the look of it.

eg. `http://superuser.com/quest*`

Comment: http://www.ehow.com/how_6507904_block-website-opera.html  as opera user i did it this way but i would prefer a system wide way of blocking the sites.

Comment: @Creedy: I doubt that will be possible, as the system or router will not have any business regarding specific paths of websites - only at a (sub)domain level.

Comment: ok.. 3 browser have to be enough :D and i'm fine with the opera way - thanks to opera link it even is sync'd with my other machines.    maybe some day i'll come up with another solution suitable for internet explorer as well..